# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' one fetch works the other doesn't

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I know this question has been asked a thousand times before but I can't seem to figure out why one fetch request works but the other doesn't.

The error I get : "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Here's the working one

```
let responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log(response)
  let lastName = response.profileObj.familyName
  let firstName = response.profileObj.givenName 
  let email = response.profileObj.email 
  let tokenid = response.googleId

  let userData={
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    token_id: tokenid
  }

  window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/")

  return fetch('/api/user', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}
```

but this one doesn't

```
handleClick = (name, symbol, price) => {
    this.props.setMessage()
    let userData={
      name: name,
      symbol: symbol,
      priceAtSubscription: price
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData))
    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/user', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
  }
```

This is very important, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key difference between these requests. The first one seems to be making a request to same origin as the client server. This is why your url is simply `/api/user`. When a client is making a request to a server of the same origin you do not need to include the origin in the URL and there is no issue with CORS.

Your second URL `http://localhost:5000/api/user` included the origin in the URL as well. Now your first URL may be working either due to a proxy, or due to the fact that the client is being served by the same server.

In the case of a proxy, including the origin would by pass the proxy giving you a CORS error.

In the case where the second request is going to another server, then you need to ensure that server will allow request from this client.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Chaim you are a scholar and a person. This helped tremendously in understanding what is going on thank you!

Comment: really glad to help!